# How do you delete lines with certain keywords in VScode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have this regular expression to find certain keywords on a line:

```
.*(word1|word2|word3).*
```

In the find and replace feature of the latest VSCode it works ok and finds the words but it just blanks the lines leaving **big gaps** in-between.

I would like to delete the entire line including linefeed.

The find and replace feature doesnt seem to support reg exp in the replace field.

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings

Answer (score 308, accepted):

If you want to delete the entire line make your regex find the entire line and include the linefeed as well. Something like:

```
^.*(word1|word2|word3).*\n?
```

Then <kbd>ALT</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd> will select all lines that match and <kbd>Delete</kbd> will eliminate them including the lines they occupied.

Comment: Ctrl + Shift + K for delete line.

Comment: don't forget to enable regex

Comment: `Command` + `Shift` + `K` to delete line on Mac

Comment: You can also fire the replace with an empty field, instead of using a keyboard combination. It works fine also.

Comment: Dont work on linux. The line is cleaned but not deleted

Answer (score 12):

[image: Mark's answer as an example in VSCode]

Mark's answer as an example in the VSCode screenshot for those who need extra guidance. Click on the '.*' icon followed by 'replace all' with a blank entry to delete, or your replacement text.

Clicking the X icon next to a result allows you to dismiss that result from the replace function

[image: Dismiss result]

Answer (score 2):

I had need to remove lines with [,,] where some blank values from a DB export couldn't be tolerated in the database I was migrating to. The specific regex string to use there was

```
^.*,,.*?\n
```

Posting this for my own future reference as much as anything.