# How do you select lines with certain keywords in VScode in Brackets off CSS Classes

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

I have a long CSS file and want to clean it up by removing the different lines and copying them into the appropriate Scss file:

> _layout.scss,
> _colorscheme.scss,
> _type.scss

The regex from the following thread is a great approach:
[How do you delete lines with certain keywords in VScode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51287097/how-do-you-delete-lines-with-certain-keywords-in-vscode)

However, class names are also matched, see example:

Regex:
`^.*(radius|width|box-shadow|padding|margin|display:|height:).*\n`

Code-**Example**:

```
.margin-text-class {
    margin: 1rem;
    color: #fff;
}
```

For the sake of completeness, here are my current regex to separate.

Regex for fonts:

`^.*(font|line-height|letter-spacing).*\n`

Regex for colors:

`^.*(color:|background-color|rgba).*\n`

I found a regex that selects everything within the brackets:
*Currently only when everything is in one line.*

`(?<=\{)(.*?)(?=\})`

Does anyone have any idea how to combine these?

Comment: Try `^[^\r\n{}]*\b(?:radius|width|box-shadow|padding|margin|display:|height:)[^{]*\{(?:\r?\n(?!\s*\}\s*\}).*)*\r?\n\s*\}` https://regex101.com/r/UaSNRH/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading the posted answer, if you want to get all the lines after the `{` without matching `}` until the first occurrence of margin, you might also use a negated character class matching any char except `}`

```
\{[^\r}]+?\bmargin\b.*\r?\n
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/92ML5u/1)

If margin can only be at the next line, you can match a newline after `{` and then match margin in the next line making sure the line does not contain `}`

```
\{\r?\n[^\r\n}]*\bmargin\b[^\r\n}]*\r?\n
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZfyCQA/1)

Note that these patterns match a format as in the example data, and do not take any nesting into account.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Thefourthbird, your regex unfortunately selected the whole block, but I only needed the corresponding line. But the code helped me a lot because I was able to adapt it with it.

If someone else needs it, example for margin:

`(?:\{)(?:\r?\n(?!\s*\}\s*\}).*)(^.*)(?=margin)(.*\n)`

*I use the regex to search and replace it with `{`*

Comment: Perhaps this would also work in that case `\{(?:\r?\n(?!\s*\}).*?\bmargin\b.*\r?\n)` https://regex101.com/r/wQgiHT/1

Comment: Thank you @Thefourthbird